# Using same button to select two (non-conseuctive) files in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 text fields and one "select file" button. I need to use this button to select two files and fill the selected file name in its corresponding text field. I've tried the following code, but the problem with it is that I currently need to select the two files in a consecutive way. This doesn't give a good user experience, as the first file is in the first text field and the second is on the 5th text field. Accordingly, I need a way to select those files, not in a consecutive manner.

Code:

```
def browsefunc1():
    filename =filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("rpt files","*.rpt"),("All files","*.*")))
    inputtxt1.insert(tkinter.END, filename)


def browsefunc2():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("fss files","*.fss"), ("All files","*.*")))
    inputtxt5.insert(tkinter.END, filename)

def call_func():
    browsefunc1() # This function happens before the next
    browsefunc2()

fileButton = tkinter.Button(window,text="Select File",command=call_func)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and try to be more clear; currently, it's hard to tell quite what you're asking.

Comment: Edited. Please Check
@SamMatzko

Comment: This is better, but the goal if a minimal reproducible example is that it can be copied, pasted, and run. This code has indentation errors, missing imports, and undefined variables. I can fix it so that I can run it; but please try to improve the code. How many lines is your whole program?

Comment: My understanding is that you want to call `browsefunc1()` if current focused widget is `inputtxt1` or call `browsefunc2()` if current focused widget is `inputtxt5`, is it right?

Comment: yes. @acw1668..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want is:

- call `browsefunc1()` when `inputtxt1` has the focus
- call `browsefunc2()` when `inputtxt5` has the focus

Then you can use `window.focus_get()` to get the widget that has the focus and then call the corresponding function based on the focused widget:

```py
def call_func():
    widget = window.focus_get()
    if widget is inputtxt1:
        browsefunc1()
    elif widget is inputtxt5:
        browsefunc2()
```